# How to make hairs in particle system appear 3d in Blender 3.6?

Tags: 3d-view, particles, hair

I was doing this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtjj2vcbgnc)
and in a moment 1:37 he explains how to switch viewing hair particles in 3d via *Render Settings > Curves > 3D Curves*.

[image]

However, this options seems to be missing in Blender 3.6.1. I tried to research but couldn't find any info about it. Where is this option?

Comment: We can't help with Blender versions that haven't been released yet!

Comment: I didn't realise that 4.0 is alpha. I downloaded 3.6.1. now but it has the same issue.

Comment: You have to switch from the Particles tab to the Render Settings tab on the Properties pane which he does at https://youtu.be/dtjj2vcbgnc?t=90 in the video before you can find that setting. - It's the same in both 3.5.1 and 3.6.1. As Harry says, you do need to be using Cycles rather than Eevee.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch *Render Engine* to *Cycles*

[image]